# Electron errors "The "path" argument must be of type string" in the console

Tags: javascript, electron

electron app code from the book Cross-platform Desktop Applications, It  aims to display the users file directory like in a desktop explorer application to the browser.

```
    const os = require('os'); 
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const async = require('async');
  


    function getHomeFolder (){
    return os.homedir();
    }
    function retrieveFiles (folderPath,cb) {
       fs.readdir(folderPath,cb);
    }


    function inspectAndDescribeFiles (filepath,cb) {
    let result = {
        file:path.basename(filepath),
        path:filepath,type:''
    };
    fs.stat(filepath,(err,stat) =>{
        if(err){
            cb(err);
        }else{
            if(stat.isFile()){
                result.type = 'file';
            }
            if(stat.isDirectory()){
                result.type = 'directory';
            }
            //cb(err,result);
        }  
    });
    }
    function inspectAndDescribeFiles(folderPath,files,cb){
        async.map(files,(file,asyncCb) => {
            let resolvedFilePath = path.resolve(folderPath,file);
            inspectAndDescribeFiles(resolvedFilePath,asyncCb);
        },cb);
    }
    function displayFileIcons (file){
    const mainArea = document.getElementById('main-area');
    //const template = document.querySelector('item-template');
    //let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    const img = document.querySelector('img').src = './assets/foldericon.png';
    const fileImg = document.querySelector('.filename').innerText =file.file;
    //clone.querySelector('img').src =`assets/${file.type}.png`;
    //clone.querySelector('.filename').innerText =file.file;
    mainArea.appendChild(img);
    }
    function displayFiles (err,files){
    if(err){
        return alert("Sorry we couldn't display your files");
    }
    //files.forEach((file)=>{console.log(file); });
    files.forEach(displayFileIcons);
    }
    function main () {
    const folderPath = getHomeFolder();
    retrieveFiles(folderPath,(err,files) => {
       if(err) {
           return alert('Sorry we could not load your home folder');
       }
     //    files.forEach((file) => {
          
     //     console.log(`${folderPath}/${file}`);
     //    });
     inspectAndDescribeFiles(folderPath,files,displayFileIcons);
     });
     }
     main();
```

The error printing to the developer tools console reads "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined.What I'm I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This line: `inspectAndDescribeFiles(resolvedFilePath,asyncCb);`. `inspectAndDescribeFiles` takes three arguments, not two.